# mocking a read to a file with a non-standard library

Tags: python, testing, mocking, h5py

I would like to set up a test and mock a call which reads an attribute from a file. I'm using the non-standard library `h5py`, but this question could apply to other data reading libraries. For example, the code I'm trying to mock looks like:

```py
import h5py

with h5py.File('/my/data.h5') as f:
    assert f.attrs['short_name'] == 'expected_output'
```

[This reference](https://otrabalhador.github.io/python-testing-by-examples/docs/en/mocking/examples/reading-writing-on-files.html) shows how to use `mock_open` to patch some text to the file read, but how does one patch a more complex Python data structure?

If it's easier, I don't necessarily need to get the `h5py` data structure, I just need to patch that a call to `f.attrs['short_name']` would return a particular string value. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would go this approach, at least at the start:

```
def test_get_instruments(self, mocker):
    db = mocker.Mock()
    sess = Session()
    mocker.patch.object(db, "get_session", return_value=sess)
    mocker.patch.object(db, "select", return_value=[{"id": 1}])

    resp = get_data(db, req.dict())

    db.get_session.assert_called_once()
    db.select.assert_called_once_with(sess, DataType)
```

Step-by-step:

1. Create a mock object that could mimic any behaviour
2. Add some *fake* methods with possible return types using **patch**
3. Check that mock has been called as you expect it to be called

If you care for testing some h5py internals, you might follow similar road